# Regex for 0 in the middle, but not at the end

Tags: java, regex

I need a regex so that I can extract the end of the string prepended by 0:

1. 10001 => 01
2. 2010 => 010
3. 10013 => 013

Tried with "0(\d+)$", but doesn't work for 2010

I always check on numbers of this format format "%d00%d" or "%d0%d", so there's always a 0 in the middle, and it's always starting with a number greater than 0, and end with a number greater than 0.

Comment: Why not just scan the string from the right until you find a non-zero digit, then until you find a zero. And what does `000` become? What about `111`?

Comment: it's always a number in this format "%d00%d" or "%d0%d", so there's always a 0 in the middle

Comment: Isn't it just `\d*(0\d+)`? Or are there further requirements?

Comment: Maybe try [`0*(0\d+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/QRHFeo/latest)

Comment: alternative `0(?!0)\d+$` (assuming `000` is not valid, even being in "%d0%d" format)

Comment: "but doesn't work for 2010" Why not? If you intended to actually capture the zero, why don't you use `(0\d+)$`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
0[1-9]+0*$
```

- `0` matches leading "0"
- `[1-9]+` matches non "0"s
- `0*` allows optional trailing "0"s
- `$` anchors pattern to end of line

See: https://regex101.com/r/kLeTNP/latest

Answer (score -1):

this regex works fine  with input : "2010"

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "2010";

        String result = extractEndingAfterZero(input);

        System.out.println("Input: " + input + ", Output: " + result);
    }

    public static String extractEndingAfterZero(String input) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("0(?!0)(\\d*)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            String extractedPortion = matcher.group(0);
            return extractedPortion;
        } else {
            return input;
        }
    }
```

Comment: you are right ,my mistake, i just made a modification can you test again